# Запятая в предложении (2)

Tags: ссп

Можно ли не считать "раньше" общим второстепенным членом в данном предложении?

*Раньше у него был магазинчик(,) и все эти вещи продавались за бесценок, прежде чем их передали музею.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно. В конце концов, кто, кроме автора, может точно знать, относится ли этот член к обеим частям?! Я бы точно не считал, что "раньше" как-то связано со второй частью. Здесь на то есть особая причина - второе предложение и без того усложнено придаточным предложением с союзным словом того же типа - временного.

"Раньше" при наличии "прежде" вызывает ощущение избыточности. Поэтому его действие лучше ограничить первой частью. Но, повторюсь, на то - воля автора, однозначных рекомендачий тут вряд ли можно ожидать.